# Everyone wants us

Tags: riddle, haiku

> You want us so much
>   But when you get us, regrets
>   You won't be the same

What are we?

Extra verse:

> Well, many you know
>   Take us for granted. We're the
>   One who welcomed them!

Hint:

> We are `0b11` things.

Comment: For me? 11 kinds of chocolate and then the regrets of having a stomach ache

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Hahaha. That isn't the answer, but great answer!

Comment: If I hadn't said it someone else would :)

Comment: I've noticed many of your riddles seem to have a lot of false positive answers. Please try to narrow them down sufficiently before they're posted.

Answer (score 2):

I want to say:

> Triplets! :D

You want us so much

> Most people want to have kids

But when you get us, regrets

> Triplets = 3 times the crying and pooping

You won't be the same

> Duh! you are a parent now or a zombie (no sleep)

Comment: No, but it's a good false positive you found!